# how to get detailed information about execution of a script in groovy

Tags: debugging, groovy, expression

I found [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0.RC2/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew) a very good example of what I want:

[image]

Basically to be able to execute a String as a groovy script with an expression, but if the condition is false, I want to show detailed information about why it was evaluated as false.

**EDIT**

I want an utility method that work like this:

```
def expression = "model.book.title == \"The Shining\""
def output = magicMethod(expression)

// output.result: the exact result of executing expression
// output.detail: could be a string telling me why this expression returns true or false, similar to de image
```

I think it may be a combination of `Eval.me` + `assert` and to catch the exception in order to get details

Comment: So you want the message produced by the `assert` keyword but can't just use `assert`?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it works with assert, thanks for the idea @Justin Piper

here is the snippet:

```
def model = [model:[book:[title:"The Shinning"]]]

def magicMethod= { String exp ->
    def out = [:]
    out.result = Eval.x(model,"x.with{${exp}}")
    try{
        if(out.result){
            Eval.x(model,"x.with{!assert ${exp}}")
        }else{
            Eval.x(model,"x.with{assert ${exp}}")
        }
    }catch(Throwable e){
        out.detail = e.getMessage()
    }
    return out
}


def expression = "model.book.title == \"The Shining\""
def output = magicMethod(expression)

println "result: ${output.result}"
println "detail: ${output.detail}"
```